# .net validator custom error message

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a big form with many controls.
I am using .net regular validator to validate.
The submit button is at the bottom.
I'd like to display a custom error message when using click on the submit and there are validation errors.
How can I do that?

Comment: custom error for each validator? or just a custom validation summary?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ErrorMessage property of each validator and the [ValidationSummary Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic8) to display all the messages on submit.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the Custom Validator [How to: Validate with a Custom Function for ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Here is how it can be implemented...

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="invalid text"></asp:CustomValidator>

protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (Condition == true)
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```